# Does boto3 attempt to retry multipart uploads by default?

Tags: python, file-upload, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using boto3 1.4.4 do handle uploads of large files (usually hundreds of megabytes to several gigabytes) to S3 using [`S3.Client.upload_file`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file).

The boto3 docs [claim](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html) that botocore handles retries for streaming uploads by default.

> - Retries.  While botocore handles retries for streaming uploads,
>     it is not possible for it to handle retries for streaming
>     downloads.  This module handles retries for both cases so
>     you don't need to implement any retry logic yourself.

However, I have been looking through the [source code](https://github.com/boto/boto3/tree/1.4.4), and I have been unable to find any evidence that retries are actually handled for uploads. Conversely, the retry logic for downloads (using `download_file` or `download_fileobj`) is [explicit and evident](https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/develop/s3transfer/__init__.py#L521), so I'm at a loss for whether or not retries are actually handled during upload.

What follows is a partial stack trace from a failed upload, which is why I am asking the question in the first place:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/s3transfer/__init__.py", line 642, in upload_file
    self._multipart_upload(filename, bucket, key, callback, extra_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/s3transfer/__init__.py", line 739, in _multipart_upload
    uploader.upload_file(filename, bucket, key, callback, extra_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/s3transfer/__init__.py", line 393, in upload_file
    filename, '/'.join([bucket, key]), e))
  S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload [file] to [bucket]: (104, 'ECONNRESET')
```

**Does boto3 provide some guarantees retrying uploads, and if so, where is this logic implemented / documented?**

For now I have opted to use the [retrying](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying) package to make repeated calls to `upload_file`